# Python: How to call a class when something is done

Tags: python, class, variables, python-3.x

How to make an object that calls a class when certain conditions are true. E.G. If a var is true, then a new object = the class. Also the object should be different each time.

EDIT: Because of it being vague, I will try to explain. In my program I have a while loop and I want to do something in my program that changes a variable and when that variable changes, a new object is created that applies many of the class's function in the while loop.

Comment: This is far too vague to answer. Please give some examples of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a list, and everytime it gets past the if statement, append the object to the list

```
   X.append (class (parameters))
```

This way, you can easily get the objects by indexes

For example, i have a class that makes a circle, using turtle

```
class StateCircle(turtle.Turtle):
def __init__(self, color, x, y, name, i, aaa = True):
    turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
    turtle.tracer(0,0)
    self.shape('circle')
    self.shapesize(2,2,2)
    self.penup()
    self.color(color)
    self.width = WIDTH
    self.speed(0)
    ta = turtle.Turtle()
    ta.ht()
    ta.pu()
    global xxx
    global textcoordinates
    global labelnames
    ta.goto(x,y+36)
    ta.write(name, font=("Arial", 8, "normal"), align="center")
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.goto(x, y)
    turtle.update()
```

To make 4 circles, i call this inside a for loop, and append the circle objects to an array list

```
self.state_circles.append(StateCircle('yellow', coordx, coordy, label, i))
```

The For Loop would be:

```
for i in range(4)            #Or any range
    self.state_circles.append(StateCircle('yellow', coordx[i], coordy[i], label, i))
    #Coordx and Coordy are lists that hold the coordinates of 4 different places
```

Now, whenever i need to refer to the first circle, like to change the color, i can use

```
self.state_circles[0].color(colorname)
```

Comment: Can you further explain how to do this?

Comment: Is the for loop in the class?

Comment: edited, and no, its when you call it @Orange1861